# Is there constructivist proof for this measure theory fact?

Tags: measure-theory, alternative-proof, constructive-mathematics

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},m),(Y,\mathcal{C},p)$ be measure spaces and let $(X\times Y, \mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{C},m \times p)$ be the product space. Let $E \in \mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{C}$. For $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, define the fibers $E_x=\{y \in Y:x \in X\}$ and $E^y=\{x \in X:(x,y) \in E\}$.

Our fact is that $E_x \in \mathcal{C}$ and $E^y \in \mathcal{B}$ for all $x \in X$ and $y\in Y$. This can be proven by defining the collection $\mathcal{M}=\{E \in \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B}:\forall x\in X, \forall y \in Y,E^y \in \mathcal{B},E_x \in \mathcal{C} \}$, and showing $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal{R}=\{B\times C:B \in \mathcal{B}, C \in \mathcal{C}\} \subset \mathcal{M}$.

I was wondering if there was a more constructivist proof of this. If $E \in \mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{C}$, is there some constructive process to show $E_x \in \mathcal{C}$?

Comment: To me it seems that up to this point nothing non-constructive has happened. You may need to link to / elaborate the proof.

Comment: @Lereau, there is nothing else to the proof (other than observing that $\mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{C}$ is, by definition, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{R}$).

Comment: @Spencer, the problem is that $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are arbitrary per your question.  It's hard to imagine a more concrete argument.  (How would you go about proving that $E_{x} \in \mathcal{C}$, bearing in mind that your proof has to work for all possible $\mathcal{C}$?  All you have at your disposal is that $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and the definition of $\mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{C}$.)

Comment: @PeterMorfe You are correct, my bad. I suppose I was wanting to see some "algorithm" where given a measurable set in some product space, I can find show its fiber is measurable.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler, even then, it's hard.  It's not clear how to identify whether or not a given set is in the product $\sigma$-algebra, let alone construct an algorithm.  The only thing we have is the minimality property in the definition of product.